# Re-write dict keys when sorting dict

Tags: python-3.x

I have some code that sorts a dict based on time stamps in a value which works ok.

The keys of my original unsorted dict are integers in ascending order (1, 2, 3...)

My dict looks similar to this:

```
{1: {'pkt_no': '127', 'timestamp': 1563841184.505932}, 2: {'pkt_no': '128', 'timestamp': 1563841184.506147}}
```

I am using the following code to sort the dict:

```
sorted_packets = sorted(stream['packets'].items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['timestamp'])
```

After the sort, the keys as expected are in some other order such as 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6... etc.

I would like to update/rewrite all the keys in the sorted dict so that they are in ascending order again (starting from 1), while the actual items remain in the newly sorted order.

How do I do that most efficiently with **Python 3.7.3**.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just a list then ?

Comment: You should provide a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the original keys, just use the `values` - then it's just a matter of building a new dict from the values and their index (that you can get using `enumerate(seq, [start=0])`:

```
src = {1: {'pkt_no': '127', 'timestamp': 1563841184.505932}, 2: {'pkt_no': '128', 'timestamp': 1563841184.506147}}
sorted_vals = sorted(src.values(), key=lambda x: x['timestamp'])
result = {i:v for i, v in enumerate(sorted_vals, 1)}
```

Comment: Thank you. Using values and building a new dict with enumerate(seq, [start=0]) provided the results I needed.